# What's the meaning of global in getGlobalCallbackQueue()?

Tags: ros, callbackqueue, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

Does the getGlobalCallbackQueue function return a pointer to a queue shared by all the nodes? or does it return a pointer to a queue intended global within the node?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11970/what%27s-the-meaning-of-global-in-getglobalcallbackqueue()?/) by [sciarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1397/sciarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2011-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a pointer to the default callback queue for that node. All callbacks by default in that node use this callback queue, unless specified otherwise at construction.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3